# How to seperate list elements as Char or Float

Tags: haskell

When I take a mixed tree from char and float I have to seperate them as a Float or Character in haskell and add them to the specific list I tried to write something as you can see below;

I tried to take a as [a] in the else part but it gives error too.

```
data BETree = Leaf Float | Node Char BETree BETree deriving (Show, Ord, Eq)

charList :: [Char]
charList = []

floatList :: [Float]
floatList = []

toList :: BETree -> ([Float], [Char])
toList (Node a l r) = if (a :: Char ) then (charList ++ [a])
                      else (floatList ++ a)
```

I expect to entered values to seperate for floatList and charList however I get errors like this;
Couldn't match expected type ‘[[Char]]’ with actual type ‘Char’
OR
vice versa

Comment: data BETree = Leaf Float | Node Char BETree BETree deriving (Show, Ord, Eq)

Comment: Do you want to know how to implement this function `toList' :: BETree -> ([Float], [Char])`?

Comment: If the Node a is char then it will add a to the charList. However, If it is Int then it adds Node a to intList. I'm trying to find this but I'm getting errors about the type of a

Comment: You said `Int`, but there's no `Int` in the data type.  Did you mean `Float` instead of `Int` or vice versa?

Comment: Yes, that was my mistake sorry. Trying to check if it is Float or Char

Comment: `if (a :: Char)` is wrong because `if` takes a `Bool`, not a `Char`. Also, the type annotation is redundant because `a` is already a `Char`.

Comment: `floatList ++ a` is two type errors: `++` takes two lists, but `a` is not a list (it's a single `Char`), and `floatList` is a list of floats, to which you cannot add `a` (because it's a `Char`, not a `Float`).

Comment: Oh, I understand my mistake thank you

Comment: Interesting problem. I hope this wasn't given as a homework.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of aspects of Haskell that you haven't mastered yet, and they're causing you some difficulty.

First, as you probably know, Haskell takes its types very seriously.  It's a strongly typed language, so that means that the whole concept of searching through a data structure to find values of a particular type is the wrong way of thinking about this problem.  The definition of `BETree` is:

```
data BETree = Leaf Float | Node Char BETree BETree deriving (Show, Ord, Eq)
```

which says that this structure consists of `Leaf`s that contain a `Float` and internal `Node`s that contain a `Char`.  So, if you want to find all the `Char` values, you don't check the *types*, you just look for the `Node`s.  They will all contain `Char`s and can't contain anything else, by the definition of `BETree`.  In other words, in your function definition:

```
toList (Node a l r) = ...
```

you don't need to try to check the type of `a` -- it's guaranteed to be `Char` by the definition of `Node` in the `BETree` definition.  If you separately write a definition:

```
toList (Leaf x) = ...
```

then you're similarly guaranteed that `x` is a `Float`, and you don't need to check any types.

Second, Haskell normally works with immutable values.  This means that, unlike in most other languages, you usually *don't* start by creating an empty list and then trying to add elements to it in a separate function.  Instead, you usually write recursive functions that return the "list so far", which they generate by adding an element (or elements) to the list returned by recursively calling themselves.  As a simple example, to write a function that builds up the list of all positive integers in an input list, you'd write:

```
positiveInts :: [Int] -> [Int]
positiveInts (x:xs) | x > 0 = x : positiveInts xs  -- add "x" to list from recursive call
                    | otherwise = positiveInts xs  -- drop "x"
positiveInts [] = []
```

So. here's how it might work for your problem, starting with the simpler problem of **just** building the `floatList`:

```
toFloatList :: BETree -> [Float]
toFloatList (Leaf x) = [x]        -- x is guaranteed to be a Float, so return it
toFloatList (Node _a l r) =       -- _a can't be a float, so ignore it
  toFloatList l ++ toFloatList r  -- but recurse to find more Floats in Leafs
```

And test it:

```
> toFloatList (Node 'x' (Leaf 1.0) (Node 'y' (Leaf 3.0) (Leaf 4.0)))
[1.0,3.0,4.0]
>
```

Building just the `charList` is only slightly more complicated:

```
toCharList :: BETree -> [Char]
toCharList (Leaf _x) = []       -- x is guaranteed to be a Float, so no Chars here
toCharList (Node a l r) =       -- "a" is a Char
  toCharList l ++ [a] ++ toCharList r  -- recurse and put "a" in the middle
```

and testing it:

```
> toCharList (Node 'x' (Leaf 1.0) (Node 'y' (Leaf 3.0) (Leaf 4.0)))
"xy"
> "xy" == ['x','y']
True
>
```

In Haskell, the list of Chars `['x','y']` is equivalent to the string `"xy"` which is why it gets printed this way.

Now, the easiest way to define `toList` is:

```
toList :: BETree -> ([Float], [Char])
toList bet = (toFloatList bet, toCharList bet)
```

This traverses the tree twice.  If you want to build both lists together in a single traversal, things get significantly more complicated:

```
toList' :: BETree -> ([Float], [Char])
toList' (Leaf x) = ([x],[])   -- easy, since Leaf contains only one Float
toList' (Node a l r) =        -- Nodes are harder
  let (fl1, cl1) = toList' l  -- lists from the left branch
      (fl2, cl2) = toList' r  -- lists from the right branch
  in  (fl1 ++ fl2, cl1 ++ [a] ++ cl2)   -- combine with our Char "a"
```

and the test:

```
> toList (Node 'x' (Leaf 1.0) (Node 'y' (Leaf 3.0) (Leaf 4.0)))
([1.0,3.0,4.0],"xy")
> toList' (Node 'x' (Leaf 1.0) (Node 'y' (Leaf 3.0) (Leaf 4.0)))
([1.0,3.0,4.0],"xy")
>
```